# proxy to a running server on localhost in webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, express, proxy, webpack

I have a server with an api running at `www.mysite.com` (for example). My webpack dev server is running at `localhost:3000`. I want to make it so that all requests are routed as if it were on `www.mysite.com`.

since I am using `webpack@2.2.0` and `webpack-dev-server@2.2.0`, I noticed that there exists a property called [proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) (documentation linked).

> Proxying some URLs can be useful when you have a separate API backend development server and you want to send API requests on the same domain.

Is it possible to route all requests to `localhost:5000` or some other domain using this API? I've tried something like as follows, but to no avail

```
proxy: {
  '/': {
    target: 'www.mysite.com',
    pathRewrite: { '^/': "" },
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to get this straight - you want all client requests to go to `mysite.com` and you want those requests internally to be serviced by the webpack dev server, right?

Comment: I want to effectively make requests _from_ mysite.com to mysite.com, if that makes sense, because of same origin behavior

Comment: It sounds like the server hosting www.mysite.com should proxy to webpack-dev-server, not the other way around likre you're trying to do.